# How to show user aliases in python

Tags: python, debian

I am trying to make a scrip in python to show the aliases of a user I picked just like when you type alias in the terminal. 
so far the code goes like this:

```
tt = open("/etc/passwd" , "r")
 with tt as f2:
    with open("passwd" , "w+") as f1:
        f1.write(f2.read())
        f1.seek(0,0)
        command = f1.read()
        print
        print command

chose = raw_input("select user's name from this list > ")
rootlist = "1) Show user  groups \n2) Show user id \n3) Show users alias\n4) Add new alias \n5) Change Password \n6) Back"
print
print rootlist
print
chose2 = int(raw_input("Choose a command > "))
if choose == 3:
   os.system("alias ")
```

however os.system("alias ") doesn't work and I can't seem to find a proper way t do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias is a shell builtin which can be seen here

```
$ type -a alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

This is the problem, which you can solve by adding a call to `bash` to your shell command

```
import os
os.system('bash -i -c "alias"')
```

or the preferred way using subprocess module

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = 'bash -i -c "alias"'
event = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = event.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```